# Missing logic in tagging with Terraform (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've faced an issue while creating tags for network interfaces, in AWS

I've created an `aws_ec2_tag` resource, and tagged each created network interface with nested names of availability zones however, the **tags**, does not behave as expected (shown in image).

**AWS NETWORK INTERFACES**

[image: AWS NETWORK INTERFACES]

Current appearance:

```
UNMANAGED | EU-WEST-1A  eu-west-1b
UNMANAGED | EU-WEST-1B  eu-west-1c
UNMANAGED | EU-WEST-1C  eu-west-1a
```

Expected appearance:

```
UNMANAGED | EU-WEST-1A  eu-west-1a
UNMANAGED | EU-WEST-1B  eu-west-1b
UNMANAGED | EU-WEST-1C  eu-west-1c
```

Here is the `main.tf`

```
resource "aws_ec2_tag" "def_eni_sqs_private" {
   count        = length(var.availability_zones)
   resource_id  = element(flatten([for interface in aws_vpc_endpoint.sqs: interface.network_interface_ids]), count.index)
   key          = "Name"
   value        = join(" | ", [ UNMANAGED, upper(element(var.availability_zones, count.index)) ])
}
```

Please help me to resolve this logic

As requested here is the variable **availability_zones**

```
variable "availability_zones" { 
    type = list(string)
    default = data.aws_availability_zones.network_zones.names
}
```

Comment: It looks like `var.availability_zones` is ordered incorrectly. Can you please add the piece of code that defines `var.availability_zones`?

Comment: Hello @DennisTraub the `var.availability_zones` is a simple data statement, but in any case I've added the variable

Comment: Are you trying to tag Interface Endpoint type (aws_vpc_endpoint.sqs) for sqs?

Comment: Hi, @AsriBadlah! Yes, is has been tagged, but not how I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in this line   **count        = length(var.availability_zones)** you consider the number of interfaces is the same number of Azs
but what about if you have more than interface in the same AZ so I think it should be **count        = length(aws_vpc_endpoint.sqs.network_interface_ids)**

another one in the next line is that the return type of aws_vpc_endpoint.sqs.network_interface_ids is a set not alist, so you may casting it to a list.
The last one is reading the value of AZ from interface itself, so your code can be something like this:

```
data "aws_network_interface" "transfer_eni" {
  for_each = aws_vpc_endpoint.sqs.network_interface_ids
  id = each.value
}

resource "aws_ec2_tag" "def_eni_sqs_private" {
  count        = length(aws_vpc_endpoint.sqs.network_interface_ids)
  resource_id  = 
  data.aws_network_interface.transfer_eni[keys(data.aws_network_interface.transfer_eni)[count.index]].id
  key          = "Name"
  value        = join(" | ", [ UNMANAGED, upper
 (data.aws_network_interface.transfer_eni[keys(data.aws_network_interface.transfer_eni 
   )[count.index]].availability_zone) ])}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Asri Badlah! Just one question I missed the part, where you mapping an `var.availability_zone`, could you please mark the variable if it possible, and thank you again